# Pass month name dynamically in AWK (GNU) with control statement

Tags: linux, awk, date, variable, gnu

Hi I'm trying out below command to match month and day (of 6 days ago, which is Jun 29) to search a directory using AWK, but the result is always '0' instead it is supposed to be around 1800.

```
ls -ltr /test/output|awk  -v month="$(date --date="6 days ago" +"\"%b\"")", -v day="$(date --date="6 days ago" +%d)"  '$6 ==month && $7==day {print $9}'|wc -l
```

tried this also

```
ls -ltr /test/output|awk  -v month="$(date --date="6 days ago" +%b)", -v day="$(date --date="6 days ago" +%d)"  '$6 ==month && $7==day {print $9}'|wc -l
```

but it is working if I hardcode Month

```
ls -ltr /test/output|awk  -v month="$(date --date="6 days ago" +"\"%b\"")", -v day="$(date --date="6 days ago" +%d)"  '$6 =="Jun" && $7==day {print $9}'|wc -l
```

Please suggest what I'm missing in the code?

Comment: show `ls -ltr /test/output` output

Comment: You set `month` to the month string e.g. `Jun` PLUS A COMMA; the month in `ls -l` does not have any comma. PS: `find . [-maxdepth 1] -mtime 6` may be easier.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it is very huge, there are some 50000 files

Comment: duplicate from SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921348/pass-month-name-dynamically-in-awk-gnu-with-control-statement

Answer (score 0):

In general, parsing the output of `ls` is not a good idea. Furthermore, you only seem to be interested in the number of files, which makes your approach unnecessarily complicated. I would suggest something along these lines:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td\n" | grep -c $(date -d "6 days ago" +'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my mistake. I found another way to make it work.

The Actual approach, corrected verion:

```
ls -ltr /test/output|awk  -v month="$(date --date="6 days ago" +\%b)" -v day="$(date --date="6 days ago" +%d)" '$6 ==month && $7==day {print $9}'|wc -l
```

Here for month we need to use '\'.

Other approach

```
yesterday_date=`date --date="6 days ago" +'%Y%m%d'`
start_date=${yesterday_date}"0000"
end_date=${yesterday_date}"2359"
temp_start_date_file=$HOME/tmpstartfile
temp_end_date_file=$HOME/tmpendfile
touch -t $start_date ${temp_start_date_file}
touch -t $end_date ${temp_end_date_file}

cd /test/output
find . -type f -newer ${temp_start_date_file} ! -newer ${temp_end_date_file} -ls | wc -l
```